# tomcat can not start even with manual command

Tags: tomcat

I am working on a high availability service, my server is in active/standby working mode. My problem is that something happened to the standby server and suddenly I found that the web service can not start on the standby server. when I try to start it manually by using the start command, it gives this error:

```
/home/zserver/was/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start

PROJECT_DIR=/home/zserver
ERROR:no directory ./make!
```

Answer (score 0):

you can debug catalina.sh script to find a line where you get this error. just add:

```
set -x
```

on the top of catalina.sh right after shebang "#!/bin/sh" and check what result would be.